# Using contatenated bash commands for race condition

Tags: c, race-condition

I'm studying the race condition vulnerability, and I want to understand the basic with this simple C file:

```
int main(){

    f = open("/tmp/file",O_CREAT,0444);
    usleep(2500000);
    close(f);

    return 0;
}
```

If I understand correctly, it is vulnerable to a race condition, and I should be abble to delete "`/tmp/file`" before the program ends with this bash line:

```
./binary; rm /tmp/file;
```

(with `binary` being created by the compilation of the source code)

but it sends me

> '/tmp/file': No such file or directory

I know that using ";" to concatenate commands allows to not wait until one command return for the next one to start.

Do you have any idea why the file is not found as it's created with the binary ?

Thanks

Comment: This is off topic here, though the answer is that ; does wait - you want & ;

Comment: you want : ./binary& ; rm /tmp/file;

Comment: @crovers with your line I get this error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

Comment: I don't understand why it is off topic, isn't it about security ?

Comment: Race conditions are about security. It is on-topic to me.

Comment: Sorry - should have tried it - (./binary&); rm /tmp/file

Comment: The reason I would consider it off topic is that the issue is a bash shell issue, not a security issue - even if the reason for doing the shell command is security experimentation

Comment: @crovers I updated the title to be clearer with the security aspect of my question

Comment: Actually `./binary & rm /tmp/file` is the simplest way to accomplish it (`&` runs them in parallel, not to be confused with `&&`).  You do not need the subshell.  But yeah, a race condition is a programming problem, only **some** race conditions are security problems.